# Calculating data rate per second but the result always the same

Tags: android

Iam calculating the cellular data rate per second by using Handler, the code is being executed every second and the overall traffic been calculated then it suppose to subtract the old traffic since boot from the current traffic since boot to get the current data rate per second.

The problem I'm facing that the current data rate value is not correct, it is always giving me the total overall traffic since boot. May be I did something wrong, I'm still beginner with android. The code below.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private double RXOld;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {


            ////////////////////////Code to be executed every second////////////////////////////////////////

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            double overallTraffic = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();

            double currentDataRate = overallTraffic - RXOld;

            TextView view1 = null;
            view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view1);
            view1.setText("Current Data Rate per second= " + currentDataRate);

            double RXOld = overallTraffic;

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000 );
}
```

Comment: `double RXOld = overallTraffic;` ... java's basics ... local var vs field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Code after rectification which shall give the current data rate per second

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final double [] RXOld = new double [1];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {


            ////////////////////////Code to be executed every second////////////////////////////////////////

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            double overallTraffic = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();

            double currentDataRate = overallTraffic - RXOld [0];

            TextView view1 = null;
            view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view1);
            view1.setText("Current Data Rate per second= " + currentDataRate);

             RXOld [0] = overallTraffic;

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider using a Timer, and declare the TextView at the beginning. I think this code should work, but I didn't test it:

```
        final TextView view1 = null;
        view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view1);
        final double[] oldT = new double[1];
        Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        TimerTask tt1 = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                double overallTraffic = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
                double trafficRate = overallTraffic - oldT[0];
                oldT[0] = overallTraffic;
                view1.setText("Current Data Rate per second= " + trafficRate);
            }
        };
        timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt1,1000,1000);
```

Note: if you use a new variable into the run() of the TimerTask, the variable MUST be declared final. You can easyly change its value by makeing the variable an array of 1 element ('int[] varName = new int[1]' instead of 'int varName'), and using varName[0] instead of varName

Comment: Thanks it works, I most probably shall strengthen my java skills as it is low. While I would like to ask when you have used OldT[0], did you mean the array oldT which is zero element or you meant the first element of oldT array. excuse my question but as I said my knowledge in Java not that much.

Comment: BTW I have used the Handler way and it is working, but why have you recommended the timer way? Thanks again